# Conditional return value typing based on enum argument

Tags: python, enums, mypy, typing

I have some pydantic BaseModels, that I want to populate with values.

```
from enum import Enum
from typing import Dict, List, Literal, Type, Union, overload    

from pydantic import BaseModel


class Document(BaseModel):
    name: str
    pages: int


class DocumentA(Document):
    reviewer: str


class DocumentB(Document):
    columns: Dict[str, Dict]


class DocumentC(Document):
    reviewer: str
    tools: List[str]
```

Example Values:

```
db = {
    "A": {
        0: {"name": "Document 1", "pages": 2, "reviewer": "Person A"},
        1: {"name": "Document 2", "pages": 3, "reviewer": "Person B"},
    },
    "B": {
        0: {"name": "Document 1", "pages": 1, "columns": {"colA": "A", "colB": "B"}},
        1: {"name": "Document 2", "pages": 5, "columns": {"colC": "C", "colD": "D"}},
    },
    "C": {
        0: {"name": "Document 1", "pages": 7, "reviewer": "Person C", "tools": ["hammer"]},
        1: {"name": "Document 2", "pages": 2, "reviewer": "Person A", "tools": ["hammer", "chisel"]},
    },
}
```

To load the values into the correct BaseModel Class, I have created a System Class, which is also need elsewhere and has more functionality, but I omitted details for clarity.

```
class System(Enum):
    A = ("A", DocumentA)
    B = ("B", DocumentB)
    C = ("C", DocumentC)

    @property
    def key(self)-> str:
        return self.value[0]

    @property
    def Document(self) -> Union[Type[DocumentA], Type[DocumentB], Type[DocumentC]]:
        return self.value[1]
```

Then, through `System["A"].Document` I can access `DocumentA` directly.
To load the values, I use this function (disregard handling IndexErrors for now):

```
def load_document(db: Dict, idx: int, system: System) -> Union[DocumentA, DocumentB, DocumentC]:
    data = db[system.key][idx]
    return system.Document(**data)
```

Now, I might need to handle some of data of type B which I load directly in the handling function.

```
def handle_document_B(db: Dict, idx: int):
    doc = load_document(db=db, idx=idx, system=System.B)
    # Following line raises mypy errors
    # Item "DocumentA" of "Union[DocumentA, DocumentB, DocumentC]" has no attribute "columns"
    # Item "DocumentC" of "Union[DocumentA, DocumentB, DocumentC]" has no attribute "columns"
    print(doc.columns)
```

Running mypy raises errors on the line `print(doc.columns)`, since `load_document` has a typed return value of `Union[DocumentA, DocumentB, DocumentC]`, and obviously `DocumentA` and `DocumentC` cannot access the `columns` attribute. But the only Document type that could be loaded here is `DocumentB` anyways.

I know I could load the Document outside of the handler function and pass it instead, but I would prefer to load it in the handler.

I circumvented the type issue by overloading the `load_document` function with the correct Document class, but this seems like a tedious solution since I need to manually add an overloader for each System that might be added in the future.

Is it possible to conditionally type hint a functions return value based on an Enum input value?

Comment: It would be also great to make `db` (and db items) a `TypedDict` to have more typechecking benefits.

Answer (score 4):

You can explicitly annotate return types depending on selected option:

```py
from typing import Literal, overload

@overload
def load_document(db: Dict, idx: int, system: Literal[System.A]) -> DocumentA: ...

@overload
def load_document(db: Dict, idx: int, system: Literal[System.B]) -> DocumentB: ...

@overload
def load_document(db: Dict, idx: int, system: Literal[System.C]) -> DocumentC: ...

def load_document(db: Dict, idx: int, system: System) -> Union[DocumentA, DocumentB, DocumentC]:
    data = db[system.key][idx]
    return system.Document(**data)
```

The rest of your code typechecks now ([playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=e6de15ba12deb665079f35c28a832bad)).

Comment: `Literal` means just that: a *literal*. `load_document(some_dict, 6, x)` won't be accepted, because `x` is not one of the literals `System.A`, `System.B`, or `System.C` (even if its *runtime* value is one of those values.)

Comment: `overload` is meant to overload on argument *types*, not argument *values*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I should have stated more clearly that I already found the overload solution (see next to last paragraph in my question). But with this I need to manually write a new overload method for each enum value. I would like to somehow automatically map this.

Comment: @chepner `overload` works fine here, if call is made in form `load_document(..., system=System.A)`. It overloads on types, when argument is *literal* `System.A` - it works. Actually, `system: System` in annotation won't pass type checking if you call `load(..., system='A')` - and it is expected behavior.

Comment: @fstermann There is no such option. I'll search for related question (I'm sure I've seen it before), the resolution was "no, you can only manually write all overloads")

Comment: @SUTerliakov My point is, it may not be feasible to assume that the call will actually be made with the literal value, rather than a `System`-valued variable.

Comment: Thank you @STerliakov, very nice way to put it.